# Como implementar o tratamento de exceções em java dentro de um swtich-case?

Tags: java, exceção, try-catch

Eu tenho que fazer um tratamento para possíveis exceções dentro de uma calculadora, uma delas seria a divisão por 0, no caso "ArithmeticException", porém não estou conseguindo fazer com que funcione, mesmo após implementar o `try-catch` o código continua a retornar a mensagem padrão e não a mensagem que eu escrevi no `catch` para aquele erro:

```
case 4:
      if (num1 < num2){
       System.out.println("Impossivel realizar calculo!! \n");    
      }
      else 
      {
      int divide = num1 / num2;
      System.out.println("A divisao e: "+divide);
      }

      try{
      int divide = num1 / num2;
      System.out.println("A divisao e: "+divide);
      } catch(ArithmeticException e){
    System.out.println("Erro: divisão por zero!");
      }
    
      break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não precisa tratar a exceção, não deixe ela ocorrer, exceção só deve ocorrer se for algo excepcional, você pode evitar que ela ocorra então o faça:

```
if (num1 < num2 || num2 == 0) System.out.println("Impossivel realizar calculo!!");    
else System.out.println("A divisao e: " + num1 / num2);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/NoDivisionByZero.java).

Inclusive o código fica muito mais simples.

Isso nada tem a ver com `switch` a não ser por circunstância.